# How to export datagridview to excel using vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, excel, datagridview, printing

I have a datagridview in vb.net that is filled up from the database. I've researched and I found out that there is no built in support to print directly from datagridview. I don't want to use crystal report because I'm not familiar with it.

I'm planning to export it to excel to enable me to generate report from the datagridview.

Can you provide me ways to do this?

Answer (score 18):

Code below creates Excel File and saves it in D: drive
It uses Microsoft office 2007

FIRST ADD REFERRANCE (Microsoft office 12.0 object library ) to your project

Then Add code given bellow to the Export button click event-

```
Private Sub Export_Button_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As 
System.EventArgs) Handles VIEW_Button.Click

    Dim xlApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
    Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    xlApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue)
    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("sheet1")


    For i = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 2
        For j = 0 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1
            For k As Integer = 1 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count
                xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, k) = DataGridView1.Columns(k - 1).HeaderText
                xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = DataGridView1(j, i).Value.ToString()
            Next
        Next
    Next

    xlWorkSheet.SaveAs("D:\vbexcel.xlsx")
    xlWorkBook.Close()
    xlApp.Quit()

    releaseObject(xlApp)
    releaseObject(xlWorkBook)
    releaseObject(xlWorkSheet)

    MsgBox("You can find the file D:\vbexcel.xlsx")
End Sub

Private Sub releaseObject(ByVal obj As Object)
    Try
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj)
        obj = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        obj = Nothing
    Finally
        GC.Collect()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: You're writing everything to as text, why? Get rid of the .ToString

Comment: Also, looping is the wrong approach. You need to create an object array and write that to a range in Excel. No loop necessary except to create the object array.

Comment: @michaelZ. do you possibly have an example?

Comment: My answer below has an example of creating an object array and then setting that to a range in Excel. If you don't need formatting then you should always export to CSV because it's significantly faster than Excel automation. I'm happy to help. Review my answer and let me know if you have any questions. The above answer is fine, but you should remove the .tostring so that The data type is correct within in Excel. Otherwise you have the equivalent of a CSV as everything is text.

Answer (score 9):

**Excel Method**

This method is different than many you will see. Others use a loop to write each cell and write the cells with text data type.

This method creates an object array from a `DataTable` or `DataGridView` and then writes the array to Excel. This means I can write to Excel without a loop and retain data types.

I extracted this from my library and I think I changed it enough to work with this code only, but more minor tweaking might be necessary. If you get errors just let me know and I'll correct them for you. Normally, I create an instance of my class and call these methods. If you would like to use my library then use this link to download it and if you need help just let me know.
https://zomp.co/Files.aspx?ID=zExcel

---

After copying the code to your solution you will use it like this.

In your button code add this and change the names to your controls.

`WriteDataGrid("Sheet1", grid)`

To open your file after exporting use this line

`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("The location and filename of your file")`

In the `WriteArray` method you'll want to change the line that saves the workbook to where you want to save it. Probably makes sense to add this as a parameter.

`wb.SaveAs("C:\MyWorkbook.xlsx")`

---

```
Public Function WriteArray(Sheet As String, ByRef ObjectArray As Object(,)) As String
    Try
        Dim xl As Excel.Application = New Excel.Application
        Dim wb As Excel.Workbook = xl.Workbooks.Add()
        Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet = wb.Worksheets.Add()
        ws.Name = Sheet
        Dim range As Excel.Range = ws.Range("A1").Resize(ObjectArray.GetLength(0), ObjectArray.GetLength(1))
        range.Value = ObjectArray

        range = ws.Range("A1").Resize(1, ObjectArray.GetLength(1) - 1)

        range.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 70, 132)  'Con-way Blue
        range.Font.Color = RGB(Drawing.Color.White.R, Drawing.Color.White.G, Drawing.Color.White.B)
        range.Font.Bold = True
        range.WrapText = True

        range.HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter
        range.VerticalAlignment = Excel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter

        range.Application.ActiveWindow.SplitColumn = 0
        range.Application.ActiveWindow.SplitRow = 1
        range.Application.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True

        wb.SaveAs("C:\MyWorkbook.xlsx")
        wb.CLose()
        xl.Quit()
        xl = Nothing
        wb = Nothing
        ws  = Nothing
        range = Nothing
        ReleaseComObject(xl)
        ReleaseComObject(wb)
        ReleaseComObject(ws)
        ReleaseComObject(range)

        Return ""
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return "WriteArray()" & Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine & ex.Message
    End Try
End Function

Public Function WriteDataGrid(SheetName As String, ByRef dt As DataGridView) As String
        Try
            Dim l(dt.Rows.Count + 1, dt.Columns.Count) As Object
            For c As Integer = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
                l(0, c) = dt.Columns(c).HeaderText
            Next

            For r As Integer = 1 To dt.Rows.Count
                For c As Integer = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
                    l(r, c) = dt.Rows(r - 1).Cells(c)
                Next
            Next

            Dim errors As String = WriteArray(SheetName, l)
            If errors <> "" Then
                Return errors
            End If

            Return ""
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return "WriteDataGrid()" & Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine & ex.Message
        End Try
    End Function


 Public Function WriteDataTable(SheetName As String, ByRef dt As DataTable) As String
        Try
            Dim l(dt.Rows.Count + 1, dt.Columns.Count) As Object
            For c As Integer = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
                l(0, c) = dt.Columns(c).ColumnName
            Next

            For r As Integer = 1 To dt.Rows.Count
                For c As Integer = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
                    l(r, c) = dt.Rows(r - 1).Item(c)
                Next
            Next

            Dim errors As String = WriteArray(SheetName, l)
            If errors <> "" Then
                Return errors
            End If

            Return ""
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return "WriteDataTable()" & Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine & ex.Message
        End Try
    End Function
```

---

I actually don't use this method in my Database program because it's a slow method when you have a lot of rows/columns. I instead create a CSV from the DataGridView. Writing to Excel with Excel Automation is only useful if you need to format the data and cells otherwise you should use CSV. You can use the code after the image for CSV export.

---

**CSV Method**

```
Private Sub DataGridToCSV(ByRef dt As DataGridView, Qualifier As String)  
        Dim TempDirectory As String = "A temp Directory"  
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(TempDirectory)
        Dim oWrite As System.IO.StreamWriter
        Dim file As String = System.IO.Path.GetRandomFileName & ".csv"
        oWrite = IO.File.CreateText(TempDirectory & "\" & file)

        Dim CSV As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()

        Dim i As Integer = 1
        Dim CSVHeader As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
        For Each c As DataGridViewColumn In dt.Columns
            If i = 1 Then
                CSVHeader.Append(Qualifier & c.HeaderText.ToString() & Qualifier)
            Else
                CSVHeader.Append("," & Qualifier & c.HeaderText.ToString() & Qualifier)
            End If
            i += 1
        Next

        'CSV.AppendLine(CSVHeader.ToString())
        oWrite.WriteLine(CSVHeader.ToString())
        oWrite.Flush()

        For r As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1

            Dim CSVLine As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
            Dim s As String = ""
            For c As Integer = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
                If c = 0 Then
                    'CSVLine.Append(Qualifier & gridResults.Rows(r).Cells(c).Value.ToString() & Qualifier)
                    s = s & Qualifier & gridResults.Rows(r).Cells(c).Value.ToString() & Qualifier
                Else
                    'CSVLine.Append("," & Qualifier & gridResults.Rows(r).Cells(c).Value.ToString() & Qualifier)
                    s = s & "," & Qualifier & gridResults.Rows(r).Cells(c).Value.ToString() & Qualifier
                End If

            Next
            oWrite.WriteLine(s)
            oWrite.Flush()
            'CSV.AppendLine(CSVLine.ToString())
            'CSVLine.Clear()
        Next

        'oWrite.Write(CSV.ToString())

        oWrite.Close()
        oWrite = Nothing    

        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(TempDirectory & "\" & file)   

        GC.Collect()

    End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome options. I couldn't open the zip file. ReleaseComObject() is not defined in your posted code.

Comment: Just go into the properties of the zip file and set it to safe or something. Windows does this because it came from the internet.

Comment: ReleaseCOMObject is a method in System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal

Comment: Hi, the CSV solution works great (after some tweaking). But I cannot get the Excel solution to work. And the link to your zip seems dead.

Comment: My son keeps restarting my machine that is running my server in a virtual machine. I will get it back up soon. Feel free to contact me directly for additional help.

Comment: I moved my server VM to another machine so the downtime will be a lot less now.

Comment: Good job works well.  gridResults definition was missing in the CSV.

Answer (score 3):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    DATAGRIDVIEW_TO_EXCEL((DataGridView1)) ' PARAMETER: YOUR DATAGRIDVIEW
End Sub

Private Sub DATAGRIDVIEW_TO_EXCEL(ByVal DGV As DataGridView)
    Try
        Dim DTB = New DataTable, RWS As Integer, CLS As Integer

        For CLS = 0 To DGV.ColumnCount - 1 ' COLUMNS OF DTB
            DTB.Columns.Add(DGV.Columns(CLS).Name.ToString)
        Next

        Dim DRW As DataRow

        For RWS = 0 To DGV.Rows.Count - 1 ' FILL DTB WITH DATAGRIDVIEW
            DRW = DTB.NewRow

            For CLS = 0 To DGV.ColumnCount - 1
                Try
                    DRW(DTB.Columns(CLS).ColumnName.ToString) = DGV.Rows(RWS).Cells(CLS).Value.ToString
                Catch ex As Exception

                End Try
            Next

            DTB.Rows.Add(DRW)
        Next

        DTB.AcceptChanges()

        Dim DST As New DataSet
        DST.Tables.Add(DTB)
        Dim FLE As String = "" ' PATH AND FILE NAME WHERE THE XML WIL BE CREATED (EXEMPLE: C:\REPS\XML.xml)
        DTB.WriteXml(FLE)
        Dim EXL As String = "" ' PATH OF/ EXCEL.EXE IN YOUR MICROSOFT OFFICE
        Shell(Chr(34) & EXL & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & FLE & Chr(34), vbNormalFocus) ' OPEN XML WITH EXCEL

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your need to 'print directly from datagridview', check out this article on CodeProject:

[The DataGridViewPrinter Class](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/printing/datagridviewprinter.aspx)

There are a number of similar articles but I've had luck with the one I linked.

Answer (score 1):

The following code works fine for me :)

```
Protected Sub ExportToExcel(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExportExcel.Click
        Try
            Response.Clear()
            Response.Buffer = True
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=ExportEthias.xls")
            Response.Charset = ""
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
            Using sw As New StringWriter()
                Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
                GvActifs.RenderControl(hw)
                'Le format de base est le texte pour éviter les problèmes d'arrondis des nombres
                Dim style As String = "<style> .textmode { } </style>"
                Response.Write(Style)
                Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString())
                Response.Flush()
                Response.End()
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            lblMessage.Text = "Erreur export Excel : " & ex.Message
        End Try
    End Sub
    Public Overrides Sub VerifyRenderingInServerForm(control As Control)
        ' Verifies that the control is rendered
    End Sub
```

Hopes this help you.

Comment: Thanks this helped!

Answer (score 0):

Dim rowNo1 As Short
        Dim numrow As Short
        Dim colNo1 As Short
        Dim colNo2 As Short

```
    rowNo1 = 1
    colNo1 = 1
    colNo2 = 1
    numrow = 1

    ObjEXCEL = CType(CreateObject("Excel.Application"), Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application)
    objEXCELBook = CType(ObjEXCEL.Workbooks.Add, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook)
    objEXCELSheet = CType(objEXCELBook.Worksheets(1), Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)

    ObjEXCEL.Visible = True

    For numCounter = 0 To grdName.Columns.Count - 1
        ' MsgBox(grdName.Columns(numCounter).HeaderText())
        If grdName.Columns(numCounter).Width > 0 Then
            ObjEXCEL.Cells(1, numCounter + 1) = grdName.Columns(numCounter).HeaderText()
        End If
        ' ObjEXCEL.Cells(1, numCounter + 1) = grdName.Columns.GetFirstColumn(DataGridViewElementStates.Displayed)
    Next numCounter

    ObjEXCEL.Range("A:A").ColumnWidth = 10
    ObjEXCEL.Range("B:B").ColumnWidth = 25
    ObjEXCEL.Range("C:C").ColumnWidth = 20
    ObjEXCEL.Range("D:D").ColumnWidth = 20
    ObjEXCEL.Range("E:E").ColumnWidth = 20
    ObjEXCEL.Range("F:F").ColumnWidth = 25

    For rowNo1 = 0 To grdName.RowCount - 1
        For colNo1 = 0 To grdName.ColumnCount - 1
            If grdName.Columns(colNo1).Width > 0 Then
                If Trim(grdName.Item(colNo1, rowNo1).Value) <> "" Then
                    'If IsDate(grdName.Item(colNo1, rowNo1).Value) = True Then
                    '    ObjEXCEL.Cells(numrow + 1, colNo2) = Format(CDate(grdName.Item(colNo1, rowNo1).Value), "dd/MMM/yyyy")
                    'Else
                    ObjEXCEL.Cells(numrow + 1, colNo2) = grdName.Item(colNo1, rowNo1).Value
                    'End If
                End If
                If colNo2 >= grdName.ColumnCount Then
                    colNo2 = 1
                Else
                    colNo2 = colNo2 + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next colNo1
        numrow = numrow + 1
    Next rowNo1
```

Answer (score 0):

In design mode: Set `DataGridView1 ClipboardCopyMode` properties to `EnableAlwaysIncludeHeaderText`

*or on the program code*

```
DataGridView1.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridViewClipboardCopyMode.EnableAlwaysIncludeHeaderText
```

In the run time select all cells content (Ctrl+A) and copy (Ctrl+C) and paste to the Excel Program.
Let the Excel do the rest

Sorry for the inconvenient, I have been searching the method to print data directly from the datagridvew (create report from vb.net VB2012) and have not found the satisfaction result. 
Above code just my though, wondering if my applications user can rely on above simple step it will be nice and  I could go ahead to next step on my program progress.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way of generating a printable report from a Datagridview is to place the datagridview on a Panel object. It is possible to draw a bitmap of the panel.

Here's how I do it.

'create the bitmap with the dimentions of the Panel
Dim bmp As New Bitmap(Panel1.Width, Panel1.Height)

'draw the Panel to the bitmap "bmp"
Panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, Panel1.ClientRectangle)

I create a multi page tiff by "breaking my datagridview items into pages.
this is how i detect the start of a new page:

'i add the rows to my datagrid one at a time and then check if the scrollbar is active.
'if the scrollbar is active i save the row to a variable and then i remove it from the
'datagridview and roll back my counter integer by one(thus the next run will include this
'row.

```
Private Function VScrollBarVisible() As Boolean
    Dim ctrl As New Control
    For Each ctrl In DataGridView_Results.Controls
        If ctrl.GetType() Is GetType(VScrollBar) Then
            If ctrl.Visible = True Then
                Return True
            Else
                Return False
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

another easy way and more flexible , after loading data into Datagrid

```
Private Sub Button_Export_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_Export.Click
    Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
    file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("c:\1\Myfile.csv", True)
    If DataGridView1.Rows.Count = 0 Then GoTo loopend

    ' collect the header's names 
    Dim Headerline As String
    For k = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
        If k = DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1 Then ' last column dont put , separate 
            Headerline = Headerline & DataGridView1.Columns(k).HeaderText
        Else
            Headerline = Headerline & DataGridView1.Columns(k).HeaderText & ","
        End If
    Next
    file.WriteLine(Headerline)  ' this will write header names at the first line 
    ' collect the data 

    For i = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim DataRow As String
        For k = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
            If k = DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1 Then
                DataRow = DataRow & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(k).Value ' last column dont put , separate 
            End If
            DataRow = DataRow & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(k).Value & ","
        Next

        file.WriteLine(DataRow)
        DataRow = ""
    Next



loopend:
        file.Close()
End Sub
```