# DataGrid export to excel

Tags: vb.net, datagrid, .net-1.1

I have a `DataGrid control` that fills with a `data se`t.

I don't show all fields of data set in DataGrid control.

I want to create an `excel file` from my `DataGrid`.

How to get solution?

(windows form , `vb net 1.1`)

Comment: Do you want to export excel from datagrid?

Answer (score 1):

Try this
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680199/how-to-export-datagridview-to-excel-using-vb-net)

OR

Try This

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Dim excel As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass
Dim wBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
Dim wSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet

 wBook = excel.Workbooks.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value)
wSheet = wBook.Sheets("sheet1")

  With wBook
.Sheets("Sheet1").Select()
.Sheets(1).Name = "NameYourSheet"
End With


For i = 0 To DataGrid1.RowCount - 1
For j = 0 To DataGrid1.ColumnCount - 1
wSheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).value = DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.tosring
Next j
Next i

wSheet.Columns.AutoFit()
```

Comment: also check if the file has been created first if not then create it using `      If System.IO.Directory.Exists(tempPath) = False Then
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(tempPath)
            If System.IO.File.Exists(strFileName) = False Then
                System.IO.File.Create(strFileName)
            End If
        End If` where strFileName is the filename and tempPath is just the folder the excel file is in

Comment: how to export tp excel without using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel?

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub btnExportToExcel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExportToExcel.Click

        Dim xlApp As Excel.Application = New Excel.Application

        xlApp.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1

        Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
        Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets.Item(1)

        xlWorkSheet.Name = "Example_Export"

        For nRow = 0 To dgvDataToExport.Rows.Count - 1

            For nCol = 0 To dgvDataToExport.Columns.Count - 1
                xlWorkSheet.Cells(nRow + 1, nCol + 1) = dgvDataToExport.Rows(nRow).Cells(nCol).Value
            Next nCol

        Next nRow

        xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False

        xlWorkBook.SaveAs("C:\Example.xlsx", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, _
                           Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges)

        xlWorkBook.Close()
        xlApp.Quit()

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this one:

```
Sub create_excel(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim strFileName As string 
    Dim tw As New StringWriter() 
    Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(tw)    

    strFileName = "some_excel_from_datagrid.xls"
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.msexcel"
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & strFileName)
    Response.Charset = "UTF-8"
    Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.Default

    DataGridID.RenderControl(hw)

    Response.Write(tw.ToString())
    Response.End() 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in this princip work.

```
  String path = @"D:\users\....";
    //your path


String connStr = "Provider=//your provider;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";

            //The connection to that file

            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr);

            //The query

            string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [?]";

            //The command 

            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(/*The query*/strSQL, /*The connection*/conn);

            DataTable dT = new DataTable();

            conn.Open();

            try

            {

                OleDbDataReader dR = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                dT.Load(dR);

                bS.DataSource = dT;

                dGV.DataSource = bS;

            }

            catch (Exception ex)

            {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

            }

            finally

            {

                conn.Close();

            }
```

Comment: what is this?? it's not an export method :(

Comment: easy way: http://zamov.online.fr/EXHTML/CSharp/CSharp4.html without catch and try.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
        If Not dgv.RowCount = 0 Then
            Dim folderBrowser As New FolderBrowserDialog
            folderBrowser.Description = "Select location to save the report"
            Dim filepath1 As String = ""
            If (folderBrowser.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK) Then
                filepath1 = folderBrowser.SelectedPath
            Else
                Exit Sub
            End If

            Dim xlApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
            Dim xlWorkBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
            Dim xlWorkSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
            Try

                Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
                Dim i As Integer
                Dim j As Integer
                xlApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass
                xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue)
                xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("sheet1")
                ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
                Dim titleStyle As Excel.Style = xlWorkSheet.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Styles.Add("NewStyle1")
                titleStyle.Font.Bold = True
                titleStyle.Font.Size = "18"
                titleStyle.Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red)

                xlWorkSheet.Cells(2, 2) = "Employee Payment Report"
                xlWorkSheet.Cells(2, 4) = DateAndTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
                xlWorkSheet.Cells(2, 2).Style = "NewStyle1"
                xlWorkSheet.Cells(2, 4).Style = "NewStyle1"
                ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

                '======================================================================================================
                Dim headerStyle As Excel.Style = xlWorkSheet.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Styles.Add("NewStyle")
                headerStyle.Font.Bold = True
                headerStyle.Font.Size = "12"
                headerStyle.Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Brown)

                For k = 1 To dgv.Columns.Count
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells(4, k) = dgv.Columns(k - 1).HeaderText
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells(4, k).Style = "NewStyle"

                Next
                '=======================================================================================================
                Dim str As String = ""
                Dim l As Integer = 1
                j = 6
                Dim amt As Double = 0.0
                For i = 0 To dgv.RowCount - 1
                    amt = amt + dgv.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value
                    For m = 0 To dgv.ColumnCount - 1
                        xlWorkSheet.Cells(j, l) = dgv(m, i).Value.ToString()
                        str = dgv(m, i).Value.ToString()
                        l = l + 1
                    Next
                    j = j + 1
                    l = 1
                Next
                '======================================================================================================
                Dim lastStyle As Excel.Style = xlWorkSheet.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Styles.Add("NewStyle2")
                lastStyle.Font.Bold = True
                lastStyle.Font.Size = "12"
                lastStyle.Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Blue)
                Dim c As Integer = dgv.ColumnCount
                xlWorkSheet.Cells(j + 2, c - 1) = "Total Amount"
                xlWorkSheet.Cells(j + 2, c) = amt.ToString
                xlWorkSheet.Cells(j + 2, c - 1).Style = "NewStyle2"
                xlWorkSheet.Cells(j + 2, c).Style = "NewStyle2"
                '=======================================================================================================
                xlWorkSheet.SaveAs(filepath1 + "\EmployeePaymentReport.xlsx")
                xlWorkBook.Close()
                xlApp.Quit()

                cls.releaseObject(xlApp)
                cls.releaseObject(xlWorkBook)
                cls.releaseObject(xlWorkSheet)

                MsgBox("You can find the file at " + filepath1 + "\EmployeePaymentReport.xlsx")
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
                For Each Process In System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL")
                    If Process.MainModule.ModuleName.ToUpper().Equals("EXCEL.EXE") Then
                        Process.Kill()
                    End If
                Next
            End Try
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```